# T/F: Any of these two statements imply the third: $A$ is Hermitian, $A$ is unitary, $A^{2}=I$

Tags: linear-algebra

I think this is false because:

Assuming that $A$ is Hermitian, then $A^{H}=A$. Now I assume that $A^{2}=I$, so $A^{H} \cdot A^{H} = I$ Which doesn't imply that $A$ is unitary. So the statement is false. Is my logic correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No,  you are not correct.  Assume  $A = A^*$  and   $A^2 = I$.  Then  $I = A^2 = A^* A = A A^*$,  so $A$ is unitary.

Comment: So any of those two statements do imply the third, correct?

Comment: At this point, try to do the other implications in a similar manner.

Comment: I did and I think it is true. However the answer key says it is false?

Comment: It is true that any two of the statements implies the third.